# Django - Single Form for List of Multiple Object Instances

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm making a Django application that stores a list of athletes and displays them on a page. I have a form to create athletes but what I want to do is make a form that I can use to edit them in a pop-up window on the same page they are listed. I know I could create one form for each instance and display each form when the corresponding edit button is clicked, but that seems really inefficient. Is there any way to create one form and then essentially pass it the ID of an athlete when the edit button for that athletes is clicked?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Can you share some code?

Comment: Sorry I'm in and out of wifi until this weekend and I'll update then. I will say that I haven't started this part of my project yet so I haven't tried anything yet, but after doing some research I was having trouble finding a way to do what I wanted.

Comment: No worries, tag me in when you get a chance =)